# parse json with jquery for highcharts

Tags: jquery, json

I have json like this in a string:

```
([[1130112000000,56.79],[1130198400000,56.10]]);
```

The original json is here : [highcharts json](http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?)

and it use in here : [highcharts example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/)

In highcharts example they have used `getJSON` with a link of json inside it.

But in my program i'm generating json in the same page and i have no idea have to parse it for script!!

Comment: Your example is not valid JSON.

Comment: I know it not a valid json, that why i ask this question. any way this is how it's use in highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/) that highcharts provides, they're retrieving their json through their own callback, taking the returned data and feeding it through their `new Highcharts.StockChart` function.

To use your own json(must be properly formed json, try [this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/jstidy.htm) to help...), create the structure then do the same exact call to highcharts that they show in their example but replace the `data` variable with your data variable...

it will work without issue if everything is setup correctly...

if this doesn't help, please post more information on what you're attempting to do (with code) or else we will be going in circles...

---

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uH3m/1/) example taking the points you posted in your question and using it to create a simple highcharts graph...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON is valid, give this a try:

```
var data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That format is called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Notice that the data starts with `?()` because you specified the callback as `http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?`

You're supposed to call it specifying a method you want to use as the callback to process  the data

Therefore, you can use  http://jsfiddle.net/AF4ru/

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=hello',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
})​​​​​​​;​
```